# Im making a personality quiz and need to convert answer codes to a word

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to make a personality quiz and I want to convert the answer code I got (yes is an A and no is a B) its a simple 4 question personality quiz for kids. I have a function that puts all 4 questions "identifiers" (the A and B) into a string then I want to make an if statement that tells the program to output an answer based on that 4 letter code. So basically when it is AAAA the program needs to convert that to a Leopard(AAAA = Leopard) I have the code that outputs it to the HTML file I just need to convert that AAAA to a word.

```
function getEndingSentence() {
    var quizRadio = document.getElementsByName("rq");
    var answerCode = ''; //It's easier to handle if we simply merge all sentences into a string
    for (var i = 0; i < quizRadio.length; i++) {
        if (quizRadio[i].checked) {
            answerCode += quizRadio[i].getAttribute("data-endingsentence"); //these are the attributes used to generate quiz answers
        }
    }
    return answerCode;
}

function getAnswer() {
    var finalAnswer = ''
    var preAnswer = getEndingSentence();
    if (preAnswer = "AAAA") {
    finalAnswer = 'Jagluiperd'
    } else {
        finalAnswer = 'Undefined'// just to test if the if statment works
    }
    return finalAnswer;
}

function setEndingSentence() {
    var personalityResults = getAnswer();
    document.getElementById("results_screen").className = "";
    document.getElementById("generated_text").innerHTML = personalityResults; 

}
```

Comment: does what you have done so ar work? if so, you just need to use a switch statement instead of an if statement. Its just a simpler way to write an if statement with lots of options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: everything works except the if statement but thanks ill go check switch statements out.

Comment: Your if statement has a [single](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_assignment.asp) `=`, you need atleast two for [comparison and logic operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp). `preAnswer = "AAAA"` needs to be `preAnswer == "AAAA"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a way to do this for multiple results cause as it is your code shoud be working. If you want to convert a key into a defined value you could use an object to avoid multiple if conditions.

```
const quizResults = {
    'AAAA': 'Leopard',
    'AAAB': 'Lion', // ..and so on for each case
}

function getAnswer() {
    var preAnswer = getEndingSentence();
    return quizResults[preAnswer];
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Can you actually mark the answer as a valid one and upvote it once your question is answered please ? It helps other to understand the post better. Also @eloyra answers is actually cleaner than this one because you don't need intermediate variable to understand what is going on

Answer (score 1):

You could create an enumeration.

```
const answerMap = {
  AAAA: 'First result',
  AAAB: 'Second result',
  ...
};

function getAnswer() {
    return answerMap[getEndingSentence()];
}
```

You may want to add a guard against invalid values, but this should do the trick.
`getEndingSentence()` returns for example 'AAAA' and `answerMap['AAAA']` returns 'First result'.

Another option would be to use a switch statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch

But I think an enumeration works better.